# Take screenshot of application higher than supported resolution

Tags: windows, zoom

I am taking screenshots of an application that doesn't fit on my 1920x1080 monitor. I have to take a lot of screenshots, so I don't want to take multiple shots and stitch them together manually. Is there any way to zoom out to mimic a higher res screen? Something like a browser's ability would be perfect.

I did search on this topic, but terms like 'zoom' and 'windows' have a lot of noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just thought of this. My capture region is too tall as opposed to too wide. I set my monitor to portrait mode, rotated it, and took my screenshots. Hopefully this helps someone else too.

Answer (score 4):

You video card probably support higher resolutions. You can set it to the resolution that fits the app. with auto-panning. So the monitor can still be in 1920 and the app in the native resolution.

Another way is to open an remote desktop connection to the same PC you're using, but set a high resolution and enable the scaling option in the advanced tab. before connecting. The app will be 'zoomed' as you want - but zooming out loses resolution.

Comment: I don't have an option in my resolutions list for greater than 1920x1080. Is there something special I need to do here? I'd prefer to skip the remote desktop option (also a good suggestion) just because I don't want to tie up a second computer.

Comment: Hmmm, from this thread it seems that auto-pan is not an option in Windows7. http://www.sevenforums.com/graphic-cards/34780-no-pan-scan-virtual-desktop-windows-7-a.html

Comment: ATI and Nvidia cards normally have these options in their proprietary configuration apps. that override the native windows monitor setup app. - but I've never accessed these in Win7 - just previous wins.
Also, you don't need a second PC to use rdesktop - run the rdesktop client in the same PC you're connecting to - awkward, but I've done it once just for fun.

Comment: I coudln't remote desktop into myself on Win7 Pro because `you already have a console session in progress.` I also tried a second computer with an ATI card and you can't select resolutions over your monitors display res in Win7. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 1):

[Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) is a free program that captures the whole window when you press alt-prtscn, even if some of it is cut off. Just install, run and press alt-prtscn. It also has a number of other useful features such as allowing you to save the screenshot to a file with a pre-generated name, which can be useful if you need to create a lot of screenshots.

Comment: I enabled the interactive feature, but windows that exceed your viewport are still truncated. Thank you for the suggestion.